# How to determine why a burned DVD won't boot?

Tags: boot, dvd-burning

So I have an interesting problem where a burned DVD of "debian-7.2.0-ia64-CD-1.iso" won't boot.

The DVD is a DVD+RW. I have tried erasing, burning, and booting from "debian-live-7.0.0-i386-gnome-desktop+nonfree.iso" and that works fine, but I would rather install debian 7.2 with the x86-64 architecture.

After burning "debian-7.2.0-ia64-CD-1.sio", I can mount the CD as well and it appears that all the files show up correctly.

I was just wondering if there is any sort of boot sector I can try inspecting on the ISO to see if perhaps it is incorrect.

Thanks!

Comment: Best guess (since you seem to have used the same disc and reader for the successful boot) would be that your hardware may not be 64-bit capable. Try booting it (not installing, just booting) on another machine, and/or booting a different 64-bit LiveCD on this one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"ia64" is for the [Itanium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Itanium) CPU architecture -- it's not the x86-64 image you say you're looking for.

The x86-64 images are marked as "[amd64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64)". Here's a direct link for ya: http://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/7.2.0/amd64/iso-dvd/

Additionally, if interested, perhaps check out [this info](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=678883) regarding booting to the Debian IA64 disk image - apparently they've had trouble with it in the past (and perhaps currently as well) when it's used on a system with a EFI.

Comment: Doh! Thanks for that, I was banging my head against the wall haha.

Answer (score 0):

DVDs don't have boot sectors, and as far as I know don't even have flags that you might find on a normal HDD or pendrive. Check your boot order and that the syslinux, which I believe debian uses for live CDs, is present and configured correctly. Try testing out the iso(Or the actual CD) using VMWare, Virtualbox, or QEMU, to make sure it works.